# Is it possible to implement MySQL JSON_MERGE_PATCH with JOOQ data binding?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, kotlin, jooq

#### Question:

In my MySQL database, I have an `info` column of JSON type: `info json DEFAULT NULL,`

I wrote a simple converter as follows and registered it with the code generator:

```
class JsonMapConverter : AbstractConverter<JSON, Map<*, *>>(JSON::class.java, Map::class.java) {
    override fun from(databaseObject: JSON?): Map<*, *> =
        jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(databaseObject.toString(), Map::class.java)

    override fun to(userObject: Map<*, *>): JSON =
        JSON.json(jacksonObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(userObject))
}
```

Insert and update work fine with this converter. However, now I want to update the JSON field with MySQL's [JSON_MERGE_PATCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch) instead of simply replacing the entire JSON object on every update.

I thought of jOOQ data binding, but after a while of researching, my head started to spin because I am very unfamiliar with JDBC.

Is it actually possible to achieve what I want with jOOQ data binding?

#### Versions:

- jOOQ: 3.14.4
- Kotlin: 1.4.10
- Database: MySQL 5.7.32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever jOOQ is missing support for a vendor specific feature, use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/).

```kotlin
fun jsonMergePatch(vararg fields: Field<Map<*, *>>): Field<Map<*, *>> = DSL.field(
    "json_merge_patch({0})", 
    SQLDataType.JSON.asConvertedDataType(JsonMapConverter()),
    DSL.list(*fields)
);
```

Now you can use it as if it were an ordinary jOOQ function.

Alternatively, if you don't want to link this functionality to a specific converter, do this:

```kotlin
fun <T> jsonMergePatch(vararg fields: Field<T>): Field<T> = DSL.field(
    "json_merge_patch({0})", 
    fields[0].getDataType(),
    DSL.list(*fields)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This works for me.
Just a quick follow-up question, are you recommending against using binding in this case, or it's just not possible to achieve this feature with binding? Assuming I want to make this update behavior universal for all JSON objects in my DB,

Comment: By "binding" you mean an `org.jooq.Binding`? You didn't use one in your question, so I didn't use one in my answer... I'll make my answer a bit more generic

Comment: Thank you! This generic solution helps a lot.